# chruby's Ruby $PATH variable changing on its own when current working directory changes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, path, ruby

I installed Ruby and Rails using a guide I found here: http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you/

Notably, this guide uses ruby-install and chruby scripts to allow the installation of multiple versions of Ruby to be installed. The system I installed it on is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Everything in the installation seemed to go fine.

Now I am witnessing a baffling behavior that everything about the ruby installation stops working as soon as I leave my homedir. The reason is because it loses the paths that chruby added to the $PATH environment variable. Here is a transcript of a terminal session illustrating how $PATH is changing for no obvious reason:

```
cecil@ifrit:~$ echo $PATH
/home/cecil/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
cecil@ifrit:~$ ls -dF .*
./             .bash_logout          .bashrc  .hg/       .lesshst        .pip/         .psql_history  .screenrc         .ssh/     .vimrc
../            .bash_profile@        .cache/  .hgignore  .local/         .procmailrc*  .ruby-version  .selected_editor  .vim/     .w3m/
.bash_history  .bash_profile.ubuntu  .gnupg/  .hgrc      .mysql_history  .profile      .sc_history    .sqlite_history   .viminfo  .wakeup*
cecil@ifrit:~$ echo $PATH
/home/cecil/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
cecil@ifrit:~$ cd .local
cecil@ifrit:~/.local$ echo $PATH
/home/cecil/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
cecil@ifrit:~/.local$ cd /var
cecil@ifrit:/var$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
cecil@ifrit:/var$ ls -dF .*
./  ../
cecil@ifrit:/var$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
cecil@ifrit:/var$ cd ~
cecil@ifrit:~$ echo $PATH
/home/cecil/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
cecil@ifrit:~$
```

As long as I stay under my homedir (/home/cecil or any paths within that) everything works fine and $PATH includes the appropriate paths to the selected Ruby version and Ruby works fine from the command line. As soon as I change to any other directory on the system, the Ruby paths are removed from my $PATH and none of the Ruby executables can be accessed.

I have no idea what would cause my $PATH to change like that. I don't even know what kind of ugly hooks would be required to make it possible for environment variables to change spontaneously like that. Is this some quirk of chruby that I don't understand? What's going on here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably sourcing https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/blob/master/share/chruby/auto.sh

which includes a `trap` command in bash and a `preexec_function` command in zsh to run `chruby_auto` when you change directory.

What `chruby_auto` does is look for the `.ruby_version` file you have and set ruby from that file by changing path variables.